# How to get distinct values from typeorm find "query"

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to implement the following query on typeorm but unable to filter out the distinct values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, description, style, spec2, div FROM clothes WHERE name = 'CMD' and div  in ('B01', 'B06', 'B07', 'B09')
```

My existing code is like following.

```
    this._itemRepository.find({
      where: {
        "name" : "values",
        "div" : In(["v1","v2"])
      },
   })
```

find() method's parameter is `FindManyOptions` type but it doesn't have any attribute related to distinct values. Please help me to find a way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such option for the `find` method. For more advanced queries you can use the `queryBuilder` like so:

```
this._itemRepository.createQueryBuilder('clothes')
.select(['name', 'description', 'style', 'spec2', 'div'])
.where('name = CMD AND div IN (B01, B06, B07, B09)')
.distinct()
```

EDIT: (Maybe you need to put the strings like "CMD", "B01", ... into quotes)

Or you can do sth like that too:

```
this._itemRepository.createQueryBuilder('clothes')
.select('DISTINCT(name)')
.where('name = CMD AND div IN (B01, B06, B07, B09)')
```